# Sending JSON data as multipart-form data

Tags: python, json, multipart, httpx

I am trying to access an endpoint that is expecting multipart-form data:

```
{
  "budget_id": 0,
  "file": "string"
}
```

with parameter `content type application/json`.

I can access this endpoint via Postman, choosing a file that is JSON.

However when I have a JSON string in memory and I try to submit an `httpx` post request, I'm not sure how to encode my string.

I am sending an `httpx` post with:

```
data = {'budget-id': 9, 'file' = json_string.encode()}.
```

and I receive:

```
The submitted data was not a file.  Check the encoding type on the form.
```

Do I need to encode my `json_string` some other way?  I think if I wrote it out to a file and then opened the file I could get this to work, but it seems odd I would have to do that.